# MYSQL - Conditional write to multiple tables using NOT EXISTS clause in single transaction

Tags: mysql, transactions, sql-insert, not-exists

I have 2 tables that I need to write to in a single transaction based on a NOT EXISTS condition.

Table A - a(pk) b c

Table B - x(pk) y z

```
SET autocommit = OFF;
START TRANSACTION;

**// STEP 1**
INSERT INTO A (b,c)
SELECT r.* FROM
(SELECT 'b' br, 'c' cr FROM dual) r
WHERE 
NOT EXISTS 
(select 1 from A where c = cr);

**// STEP 2**
INSERT INTO B (y,z)
SELECT r.* FROM
(SELECT 'y' yr, 'z' zr FROM dual) r
WHERE 
NOT EXISTS 
(select 1 from A where c = zr);

**// STEP 3**
COMMIT;
```

How can I ensure that after STEP2 but before STEP3 (commit), there will not be any new inserts in A which can cause the conditional writes in STEP1 AND STEP2 to be violated.

Comment: Where's STEP 2?

Comment: @tcadidot0 sorry there was a typo. Fixed it.